# alignParentBottom working in emulator but not on device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout inside it which should stick to the bottom of the screen. I have added the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` property to it, and this works fine in the emulator, but on a real device this LinearLayout falls partially outside of the screen (I can only see the ImageViews but not the TextViews).

**Screenshot from emulator**

[image]

**Screenshot from device**

[image]

This is the full XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.test.app.MainActivity"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityTextView"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#37404d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summaryTextView"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailsView"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not bad"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainOneImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/notbad"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainOneView"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Not bad" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainTwoImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/notbad"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainTwoView"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Not bad" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainThreeImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/notbad"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainThreeView"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Not bad" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That is because of the scrolling behaviour, in that case, the last items of whatever will be scrolling are out of the screen actually. I guess what you could do is add a marginBottom to the root linearlayout? Isn't that suitable for ya?

Comment: remove android:orientation="vertical" from RelativeLayout

Comment: @NaveenShriyan Done, I was meaning to do (this was a linear layout initially) but it doesn't affect the end result.

Comment: @iBobb Yes, I could do that, no worries. As a matter of fact, I tried it and it works just fine, I was just wondering if there was another way of doing it, since it worked fine on the emulator.

Comment: @user1301428 please remove this line from root relative layout.  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: @iBobb btw, please consider turning your comment into an answer so I can accept it. It did solve the issue after all.

Comment: glad I could help and thanks for that hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of the scrolling behaviour, in that case, the last items of whatever will be scrolling are out of the screen actually. I guess what you could do is add a marginBottom to the root linearlayout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textColor="#37404d"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Not bad"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/notbad"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainOneImageView"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/notbad"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainOneView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="Not bad"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainTwoImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/notbad"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainTwoView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="Not bad"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainThreeImageView"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/notbad"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainThreeView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="Not bad"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help: on the device I still see the text views outside of the screen.